# Google Tag Manager Floodlight configuration Standard and Unique returning same results

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-search-ads-360

I have two tags set up in GTM for floodlight tags where one is set to standard counting method and the other is unique. I would expect the unique one to only fire every 24 hours as it says in the configuration, but the counts for both the standard and the unique tags are the same. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Since I didn't know: [What is Floodlight?](https://support.google.com/searchads/answer/7298761?hl=en) -- "Floodlight is the conversion tracking system for Google Marketing Platform. Like other conversion tracking systems, it consists of tags that track activity on your site, along with reporting features for adding conversion data to your reports. It uses a cookie to recognize repeat visits from a specific browser."